Can reinterpret_cast be used to cast a pointer to an unimplemented class pointer"?
I have two classes, one has an implementation and the other one doesn't. Then in the main() function, I define an instance of the class with implementation, then reinterpret_cast the address of the instance to the other class without implementation. There is no any error:
struct StructNoImplementaion;
    
struct StructWithImplementation {
    StructWithImplementation(int m) : member1(m) {}
    int member1;
};
    
int main()
{
    StructWithImplementation s73(3);
    // no error
    StructNoImplementaion* p73 = reinterpret_cast<StructNoImplementaion*>(&s73);

    // error: cannot convert from 'StructWithImplemetation' to 'StructNoImplementation'
    //StructNoImplementaion* p73 = static_cast<StructNoImplementaion*>(&s73);
}

Can someone help me understand why? reinterpret_cast doesn't need to know the memory layout of the target class? If I replace 'reinterpret_cast' with 'static_cast' then it will show the expect error.

reinterpret_cast does not need to know anything about either class, why should it need to?

reinterpret_cast is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be... Unnatural.

Reinterpret only changes the type of a pointer, which doesn't need any information about the object it points to, if any. Both static and dynamic casts do need type info and may even need to inspect the object pointed at.

Yes, you can use reinterpret_cast to convert the pointer to your unspecified type. There are only two meaningful things you can do with the resulting pointer: you can test whether it's a null pointer and you can cast it back to its original type.

"reinterpret_cast doesn't need to know the memory layout of the target class?" -- Correct, as you just demonstrated. What is your reason to expect otherwise, given this demonstration?

I did not find a duplicate question, but I did find two answers that come close to your subject: A: Struct without definition used as pointer  and A: Which one to use when static_cast and reinterpret_cast have the same effect?

Informally, reinterpret_cast on a pointer means: take the bits, and consider them as something else. There's very little you can legally do with the results: in the general case, casting back to the original type and testing for nullptr are about it. (There are some additional guarantees when casting to and from pointers to a character type, and things like reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*> to access the raw bytes will generally work if the source is a fully defined most derived class.)

reinterpret_cast on object pointers is only restricted in that it cannot cast away const-ness. There are no restrictions on the object type, so your example here is indeed legal. Compilers must compile this.
static_cast has a whole set of extra requirements, which is why that doesn't work here. But reinterpret_cast is very much a "I know what I'm doing, now shut up" cast.
